# How to fix the DB21005E An error occurred while accessing the file "DML.db2"

Tags: batch-file, db2

I'm using IBM DB2-c as my database and batch file for the command, but when I try to insert data from my database It shows the error "DB21005E  An error occurred while accessing the file "DML.db2"."

I tried to fix this using some codes but still wont work

```
:Insert
    cls
    echo.
    SET /p id="Enter ID: "
    SET /p name="Enter Tool Name: "
    SET /p course="Enter qty: "
    SET /p price="Enter price: "
    echo.
    echo.
    echo Processing...

    echo CONNECT TO TOOLSDB; >DML.db2
    echo INSERT INTO TOOL(tool_id,tool_name,tool_qty,tool_price) 
        VALUES(%tool_id%,'%tool_name%', %tool_qty%, %tool_price%); >>DML.db2

    db2cmd -c -w -i db2 -c -tf DML.db2
    pause >nul
    goto :Menu
```

I expect to insert the data after I fill up the fields. Hope someone can help me

Comment: Try to fully qualify the filename, for example use a variable to store the filename and its path.  `set db2script=c:\your_path\DML.DB2` ( to fully qualify the filename) and then `echo ... > %db2script%` and ` echo Insert ... >> %db2script% ` , then `db2cmd -c -w -i db2 -c -tf %db2script%`

Comment: `VALUES(%tool_id%,'%tool_name%', %tool_qty%, %tool_price%); >>DML.db2` is not a command. You need to `echo` it. You'll also need to redirect the line above it to the `DML.db2` too.

Comment: thanks bro It works now

Answer (score 0):

Try to fully qualify the filename, for example use a variable to store the filename and its path.

For example:

```
...
set db2script="c:\your_path\DML.DB2"

echo CONNECT TO TOOLSDB; > %db2script%

echo INSERT INTO TOOL(tool_id,tool_name,tool_qty,tool_price) VALUES(%tool_id,'%tool_name%', %tool_qty%, %tool_price%); >> %db2script%

db2cmd -c -w -i db2 -c -tf %db2script%
...
```